# Typescript type guard does not infer the right type when used with constrained generic type

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

In the below code, I expected the `data` to have `.company_id` property provided by the intellisense. However, I only get the common property. See the image below.

```js
type UserPairingg = {pairing_type: 'user', user_id: number};
type CompanyPairingg = {pairing_type: 'company', company_id: number};
type Pairingg = UserPairingg | CompanyPairingg; 

function parsee<T extends Pairingg>(data: T): T {
   if (data.pairing_type === "company") {
      data. // why doesn't it show company_id?
   }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's unfortunately not yet possible with `TypeScript`. You either have to explicitly cast it or use a [predicate method](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#using-type-predicates):

```
type UserPairingg = {pairing_type: 'user', user_id: number};
type CompanyPairingg = {pairing_type: 'company', company_id: number};
type Pairingg = UserPairingg | CompanyPairingg; 

function parsee<T extends Pairingg>(data: T): T {
   // inline predicate
   if (((d: Pairingg): d is CompanyPairingg => d.pairing_type === "company")(data)) {
      data.company_id;
   }

   // function predicate
   if (isCompanyPairing(data)) {
      data.company_id;
   }

   return data;
}

function parsee2<T extends Pairingg>(data: T): T {
   if (data.pairing_type === "company") {
      const companyPairing = data as CompanyPairingg;
      
      companyPairing.company_id;
   }

   return data;
}

function isCompanyPairing(data: Pairingg): data is CompanyPairingg {
   return data.pairing_type === 'company';
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=3.9.2#code/C4TwDgpgBAqgzhATgBQIYEtHoHYHNdQC8UA3mBlngPqiQBcUA5AK4KKMA0UrSV6AJg2zMAtgCMkAXwDcAKFrQAwgHsR5bCDSYc+IqXLbqChowDGq9SE5Rza1Br6Cow8VLkKoWyruLwkXnQIAHygVOw0AvFxpKFlZADNmbFNgdGVsKHJEBAgAHgAVKAgAD2AIbH44TwpAgD4ACn5UYFQGfIBKNtJZKF6Aej6oHAAbHGgwRAh+dFNmiB7e9HioetWnSPxOqH4hqrDLDYJCWu2AOgNvGnBoQluoACJbS3v2xubUdvbu3p-t99OnvYQI45D9JHEfgMoIlkql0plJtNZmUFkNlvV0HB9kCNm8Wp9vr8-i0ARYgSDUeDUZNgMxEBkmi05FSYSk0hksjkAEwFIqlcqVaqGfANRmtKAdLokVFLFZi841IzXIh3R5kjQvQm-czYODAGzqzSKo7E1BQVB7Q2HUFE1E-QERY2k8LAgQ2qBUn40ukM97MuKsuEZTHYx3CvHiw5bMW7UJW40EaVeiC0+mmhXCq6QFXEMyGxjMoA)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to check for a user pairing or a company pairing more often you could create **[type guards](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards)** for this:

```
type UserPairing = {pairing_type: 'user', user_id: number};
type CompanyPairing = {pairing_type: 'company', company_id: number};
type Pairing = UserPairing | CompanyPairing; 

function parse<T extends Pairing>(data: T): T {
   if (isCompanyParing(data)) {
      console.log(data.company_id);
   }
   if(isUserParing(data)) {
       console.log(data.user_id);
   }

   return data;
}

function isCompanyParing(data: Pairing): data is CompanyPairing {
    return data.pairing_type === 'company';
}

function isUserParing(data: Pairing): data is UserPairing {
    return data.pairing_type === 'user';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You still need to typecast your 'data'.

```
(data as CompanyPairingg).company_id
```